# Proper way to write a module in fortran

Tags: module, fortran

Suppose I have a module

```
module module_1
end module module_1
```

And another module which uses the first module.

- i wrote it in this way (use module in the main section)

```
module module_2
use module_1

contains
    function func_1
    end function func_1

    subroutine sub_1
    end subroutine sub_1
end module_2
```

- or should i write in this way (use module in every function and subroutine)

```
module module_2

contains
    function func_1
    use module_1
    end function func_1

    subroutine sub_1
    use module_1
    end subroutine sub_1
end module_2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering what you should do is quite opinion-based and hence off-topic. Technically, either is possible.

What we can tell you is the difference. If you use `module_1` in the whole module, it will also be acessible through host-association in any future function or subroutine you add into `module_2`. It is also use-associated and available for all type definitions and module variable definitions in `module_2`. You might want that, you might not want that. The decision is only up to you. I have certainly used either possibility many times.

If you have reasons to restrict the namespace pollution by only using `module_1` in the function and the subroutine, just go ahead and do that. But the reasons must be evaluated by you, there is no universal recipe.